# List of Cryptocurrency version bytes (address prefix)

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Where can be found the list of version byte (address prefix) for each currency following Bitcoin implementation *(P2PKH address encoding)* ?

I browsed the official Bitcoin github and the BIPs but was not able to find anything about it. Only currency IDs are listed there.

I found on the WalletGenerator.net github such a list in the code of the index.html.

ex:

```
 //name,               networkVersion, privateKeyPrefix, WIF_Start, CWIF_Start
 ("Bitcoin",             0x00,           0x80, "5",    "[LK]" )
 ("BitcoinCash",         0x00,           0x80, "5",    "[LK]" )
 ("Blackcoin",           0x19,           0x99, "6",    "P"    )
 ("Litecoin",            0x30,           0xb0, "6",    "T"    )
 ...
```

**Is there any kind of official or updated source with the list of address prefix (version byte) of all cryptocurrency?**

Answer (score 4):

The only good way to check this - look into sources. Usually these prefixes are defined in `chainparams.cpp`. I don't believe that there is somewhere up-to-date table with all prefixes for all bitcoin-based cryptocurrencies. Examples below:

[Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L132):

```
base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,0);
base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,5);
base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,128);
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xB2, 0x1E};
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xAD, 0xE4};
```

[Litecoin](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L138):

```
base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,48);
base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,5);
base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,50);
base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,176);
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xB2, 0x1E};
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xAD, 0xE4};
```

[Dash](https://github.com/dashpay/dash/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L268):

```
// Dash addresses start with 'X'
base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,76);
// Dash script addresses start with '7'
base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,16);
// Dash private keys start with '7' or 'X'
base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,204);
// Dash BIP32 pubkeys start with 'xpub' (Bitcoin defaults)
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x88)(0xB2)(0x1E).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
// Dash BIP32 prvkeys start with 'xprv' (Bitcoin defaults)
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x88)(0xAD)(0xE4).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
```

[ZCash](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L450):

```
// These prefixes are the same as the testnet prefixes
base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS]     = {0x1D,0x25};
base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS]     = {0x1C,0xBA};
base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY]         = {0xEF};
// do not rely on these BIP32 prefixes; they are not specified and may change
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY]     = {0x04,0x35,0x87,0xCF};
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY]     = {0x04,0x35,0x83,0x94};
base58Prefixes[ZCPAYMENT_ADDRRESS] = {0x16,0xB6};
base58Prefixes[ZCVIEWING_KEY]      = {0xA8,0xAC,0x0C};
base58Prefixes[ZCSPENDING_KEY] = {0xAC,0x08};
```